# tensorboard localhost connection

Tags: tensorflow, localhost, tensorboard

I can't seem to find exact question about what I am about to ask here. I just started following a Tensorflow tutorial on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9kC836XhICU&index=2&list=PLIDllPt3EQZoS8gCP3cw273Cq9puuPLTg) and got stuck at the very beginning. I wrote in my spyder IDE the below code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant(2)
b = tf.constant(3)

x = tf.add(a,b)
#writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./graphs', tf.get_default_graph())
with tf.Session() as sess:
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./graphs', sess.graph)
    print(sess.run(x))

writer.close()
```

And via anaconda terminal I activated my env (which I newly created, installed all packages required, spyder as well) I typed `python tftuts.py` and got `2018-10-05 11:50:49.431174: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
5`

Then I typed `tensorboard --logdir="./graphs" --port 6006` as suggested in tutorial I am watching.
Now, when I go to `http://localhost:6006/` the page shows
[image: this]

I am on Win10, using python 3.6.6 in Anaconda env, tensorflow 1.10.0.

How can solve this issue?

Comment: Try to use your exact IP address instead of localhost. As far as I know the other warning is benign. I get that too.

Comment: @MohanRadhakrishnan, how and where should I insert it exactly?

Comment: Try to Use IP in Browser URL .